# Date written on bottom of basement sink

Tags: basement, sink, old-house

Not exactly about home improvement, but we just bought a house and our inspector showed us that, at least here in the Northeast of the US, they would often write the date the house was completed on the underside of the basement sink. Ours lists 2/26/1936, which is pretty cool!

I'm wondering if anyone can help decipher what the other numbers mean? (Sorry for the weird angle – it's hard to get under there!)

[image]

Comment: agreed both that not home improvement and that it's darn interesting and I also want to know the answer!

Comment: I'd say it's Feb of 1935, but they weren't sure if it was the 9th, 16th or 24th. Maybe that was the last day each trade walked out? ;)

Comment: We always put a news paper in a wall. Started doing this in the 70’s after finding the walls of Victorians but they were used as insulation.